# Conditional formatting based on difference in dates is not giving results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format cell `Status` if the `Actual Date` is greater than `Completion date`.

[image: SO25606263 question example]

The above should be self-explanatory for the formulas I am using but this does not give me any result. Basically I need cell status to become red when the condition is met.

How should I do this?

Comment: Are A2 & B2 Formatted as 'General' and the formula returns real values? If they are just like in the screenshot, it won't take the dates' value.

Comment: @Alex they are both formatted as date and to make sure of it, just for test, I have used the function Today() and Today()+15. What do you mean "return real values?

Comment: Thanks; What is C2? Is there actually a date in there which it can compare?

Comment: There is nothing in C, I need c to change background color when condition is meet

Comment: Can you try adding a date in it, just to see if it would change? I believe that it looks C2's value and compares it against the formatting rules you have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not need a 2-color scale you might be better off with "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and then in the box for "Format values where this formula is true" applying

```
=B2>A2
```

This, when applied to a range such as `=$C$2:$C$100` will apply the same condition to each of C2 (to avoid highlighting the label in C1) through to C100 (or adjust to suit). If you do want yellow highlighting where the condition is not met the easiest way may be to apply 'standard' yellow highlighting (HOME, Font, Fill) to the desired range and allow CF to overwrite this when triggered.

[image: SO25606263 example]

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this using one additional cell, which determines if Date1 > Date2.

I used conditional formatting on that cell instead and it worked.

Comment: That is exactly what I have in my sheet. In cell Status (3rd cell) I have B2>A2

Comment: instead of having `B2>A2` in the condition rule, put it as formula in C2. Then check for `C2=TRUE` in condition rule, it should work.